# How can I set LC_COLLATE for a managed Postgres database in DigitalOcean?

Tags: postgresql, digital-ocean

I currently have a managed database cluster for PostgreSQL (12.16) in DigitalOcean. However, after searching documentation, I don't seem able to select/set the `LC_COLLATE` option upon database creation.

I need to alter the `LC_COLLATE` setting before the database is created as Postgres doesn't allow updating it after it's created.